# Efficient way to generate a large set of alphanumeric sequence in R?

Tags: r

I need to generate a vector with a billion ticket ids, like:

> ```
> T1
> T2
> T3
> .
> .
> .
> T1000000000
> ```

I have the following code that works:

```
c_ticket_id <- paste('T', c(0:1000000000), sep = '')
```

However, this froze up my machine and took what seemed like an eternity to complete.

I know that if it was just a numeric sequence 0:1000000000, it takes only a few seconds.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: It is probably a ram issue. `R` uses ram, so it won't allocate an object bigger than your ram size. I tried the same and got this error: `#Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb`.

Comment: "I need to generate a vector with a billion ticket ids" Why do you need this? Possibly you can avoid the `paste` and just use the numeric sequence in your application?

Comment: I thought of just using the number sequence, but I need the letter 'T' prefixed to distinguish it from other types of IDs in my app.

@patL: The thought of computing power and RAM crossed my mind, but my machine is able to complete the operation - just takes a lot of time - I wanted to run it again to measure the exact time it takes, but I cannot risk freezing up my machine again at this time. 

Just trying to find out if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @crpp you can generate less sequences (say 100000) and check how long it takes to finish. Then you can figure out how long it would take with 1 billion sequences.

Comment: Thx, in my test run a moment ago, a million took 1.38s (user) / 0.03s (system), 10 mil took 18.23s (user) / 0.18s (system), so 1 billion would probably take ~ 1800s (user). I am still researching to see if there is a more efficient way to do this, no luck yet!

Comment: As @patL noted, you're going to run into some serious memory issues. For starters, `paste()` needs to cast your numeric vector as a character, and that really blows things up: 
    pryr::object_size(as.character(0:1000000)); 56 MB.  pryr::object_size(as.character(0:10000000))
    560MB
For just the numeric half of your vector, R would allocate 56GB!  That's before even calling `paste()`, which copies the input vectors rather than modifying in place.

If you haven't already checked it out already, I highly recommend the relevant sections in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html).

Comment: Thanks, David! will check this.